# TortoiseHg on Windows 7 SSH cloning via KpyM on Windows Server 2008 R2 - no suitable response from remote hg

Tags: version-control, mercurial, ssh, windows-server-2008, tortoisehg

Backgound...

On Windows Server 2008:

- Installed TortoiseHg 2.4.2
- Created a repository and added some files and committed etc.
- Installed KpyM 1.19c

On Windows 7:

- Downloaded PuTTY
- Connected to server via SSH - works fine, can browse directories and execute commands etc.
- Installed TortoiseHg 2.4.2

Cloning a repository via SSH:

- With source `ssh://user@myhost/path/to/my/repository`
- Prompted for password once
- Nothing happens for about 5 minutes
- I get the message "no suitable response from remote hg"

Clone output:

```
% hg clone --verbose -- ssh://user@myhost/path/to/my/repository C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject
running "TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 user@myhost "hg -R path/to/my/repository serve --stdio"
no suitable response from remote hg
[command returned code 255 Fri Aug 10 17:10:42 2012]
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

**How can I troubleshoot this issue?**

**P.S. I have not done anything with public / private keys as I thought that this is only needed to avoid the password prompt.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KpyM is a good (and free) SSH Server, but it doesn't support remote commands (at time of writing).

Try Copssh - it's the only other one available for commercial use for free.